# What's de best way to create product with a lot of size options

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, custom-options

Im just a newbie in Magento developer, and I'm studying a creation of an online store, that sells rings.

**Each ring has 30 different sizes available** and, some of them has an impact on the price. For example, the ring costs $31 in size 15. Less than 15 it costs less $5 and larger than 20 costs more $5.

Totally I have around 200 rings to put in the store.

What is the best way to do this?

Creating a **configurable product** where each single product is a size, will lead to create around 4000 options.

Create **custom options** will lead in something similar, right?

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

If the rings are custom made on pre-ordering basis and you don't need **stock management per option**, then you should use **simple products** with **custom options**.

After adding one product with custom options you can just duplicate it and change the price, description, images or options.